# Want to participate, can't due to 0 reputation

Tags: discussion

I've signed up to try to participate by adding my answers to question such as these:

[Strange artifacts along window borders after waking computer from sleep mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/896221/strange-artifacts-along-window-borders-after-waking-computer-from-sleep-mode)

Because I have another solution (changing the Theme to another, then back, using Appearance settings).  It's not ideal but seems to be better for people than "compiz --replace".

Anyways I can't answer or comment.  I have no question to ask so can't get reputation that way.  I get that spammers attack msg boards, can some admin please gift me the needed reputation to contribute?  Otherwise it's a catch-22.

Comment: Also I'm on Launchpad (https://launchpad.net/kabikaboo) so you can see I'm not a bot or spammer.

Comment: You just asked a question and with my +1 you have five more points. I think  you can answer a question as a new user but I'm not positive on that.

Comment: Thank you!  I was able to submit an answer to the question in question.  :)

Comment: I am still unable to comment on the thread, but this is good progress.

Comment: @aidave, long ago, I had that problem, too.  I think many Stack Exchange users forget that when you first get started here, it's frustrating to have low reputation.  Keep in mind, once you get above some reputation threshold, the network will automatically give you +100 rep on each network site, so you'll (almost) always be able to post on any Stack Exchange site.  Hang in there!

Answer (score 12):

To expand on [WE2U's answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/17089/208574), because I'm the one who protected it...

Protection is a minor hurdle added to (usually popular) posts to prevent new users from answering questions with non-answers, like this:

> Oh yeah, I have the same issue too! I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and NVIDIA drivers 123.45! How can I fix this?

As this is a Question/Answer site (see our [tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour)), we don't exactly like these "me-too!" answers. They're not answers, and they *definitely* don't help anyone.

This site in general works on a [privilege model](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges). The more you give to a site (and the more trustworthy you become), the more you can do here. To get over the [10-rep hurdle](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/new-user), you just need to acquire 10 reputation (or 2 upvotes on a question/1 upvote on an answer).

There are, of course, [plenty of questions](https://askubuntu.com/unanswered) that would love an answer. Find one you like and/or are knowledgeable on, and answer it! Worst case, you get to do some research and learn something in the midst of writing an answer.

As of now, you have 26 reputation, which is enough to post normal answers. You're off to an excellent start, and I look forward to seeing you blossom into a great member of this community. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, and enjoy your stay!

Comment: +1 especially for "you get to do some research and learn something in the midst of writing an answer"

Answer (score 6):

The question you are trying to answer has been protected by **Kaz Wolfe**. When a question has been protected new users cannot post answers. You can post answers on 99% of the questions in ***Ask Ubuntu*** which are not protected.

Then after your other answers are upvoted you gain enough reputation to post answers on protected questions too.

Comment: I guess the problem was that the questions I am able to personally contribute to are all protected.  I'd have to wait until another question was unprotected, and then go back to the original question.  Who knows how long that would take and whether I'd remember.  Anyways I was able to submit an answer thanks to the above commenter.

Comment: Questions don't get "unprotected". Every question starts off as normal and then after it gets lots of interests / answers posted people with enough rep points decide to "protect" it. You will find 100's of thousands of normal questions you can answer on. Start answering there, gain some rep points then go back to the original protected questions you want to answer on and post your answers again. Hope this clears the air for you.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Questions will get unprotected from time to time, as the site needs dictate. It is rare, however.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to answer questions, but I'd read through the [Tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) and also take a moment to read the section on [Answering](https://askubuntu.com/help/answering) in the Help Centre first.

The [Privileges](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges) page will give you an idea of what level of reputation you require in order to contribute in different ways.